# Does anyone know how to make a css button look like this?

Tags: css, button, styles

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnYom.png)

I'm trying to make a button look like this in css but I can't figure out how. Someone please help me!

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: The link doesn't open up an image for me.

Comment: Please try at least once before asking question

Answer (score -1):

The picture is very blurry, but it should be something like this.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.button > * {
  padding: .5rem .8rem;
}

.tick {
  background: green;
}
 
.content {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">
  <div class="tick">v</div>
  <div class="content">Start</div>
</button>
```